# Read Values from .csv file and convert them to float arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, data-conversion

I stumbled upon a little coding problem. I have to basically read data from a .csv file which looks a lot like this:

```
2011-06-19 17:29:00.000,72,44,56,0.4772,0.3286,0.8497,31.3587,0.3235,0.9147,28.5751,0.3872,0.2803,0,0.2601,0.2073,0.1172,0,0.0,0,5.8922,1,0,0,0,1.2759
```

Now, I need to basically an entire file consisting of rows like this and parse them into numpy arrays. Till now, I have been able to get them into a big string type object using code similar to this:

```
order_hist = np.loadtxt(filename_input,delimiter=',',dtype={'names': ('Year', 'Mon', 'Day', 'Stock', 'Action', 'Amount'), 'formats': ('i4', 'i4', 'i4', 'S10', 'S10', 'i4')})
```

The format for this file consists of a set of S20 data types as of now. I need to basically extract all of the data in the big ORDER_HIST data type into a set of arrays for each column. I do not know how to save the date time column (I've kept it as String for now). I need to convert the rest to float, but the below code is giving me an error:

```
    temparr=float[:len(order_hist)]
    for x in range(len(order_hist['Stock'])): 
        temparr[x]=float(order_hist['Stock'][x]);
```

Can someone show me just how I can convert all the columns to the arrays that I need??? Or possibly direct me to some link to do so?

Comment: Why aren't you using `csv` module instead?

Comment: I can only get the rows right? I mean... How do I convert each column from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boy, have I got a treat for you. [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) has a `converters` parameter, which allows you to specify a function for each column as the file is parsed. The function is fed the CSV string value. Its return value becomes the corresponding value in the numpy array.

Morever, the `dtype = None` parameter tells `genfromtxt` to make an intelligent guess as to the type of each column. In particular, numeric columns are automatically cast to an appropriate dtype.

For example, suppose your data file contains

```
2011-06-19 17:29:00.000,72,44,56
```

Then

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as DT

def make_date(datestr):
    return DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

arr = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter = ',',
                    converters = {'Date':make_date},
                    names =  ('Date', 'Stock', 'Action', 'Amount'),
                    dtype = None)
print(arr)
print(arr.dtype)
```

yields

```
(datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 19, 17, 29), 72, 44, 56)
[('Date', '|O4'), ('Stock', '<i4'), ('Action', '<i4'), ('Amount', '<i4')]
```

Your real csv file has more columns, so you'd want to add more items to `names`, but otherwise, the example should still stand.

If you don't really care about the extra columns, you can assign a fluff-name like this:

```
arr = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',',
                    converters={'Date': make_date},
                    names=('Date', 'Stock', 'Action', 'Amount') +
                    tuple('col{i}'.format(i=i) for i in range(22)),
                    dtype = None)
```

yields

```
(datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 19, 17, 29), 72, 44, 56, 0.4772, 0.3286, 0.8497, 31.3587, 0.3235, 0.9147, 28.5751, 0.3872, 0.2803, 0, 0.2601, 0.2073, 0.1172, 0, 0.0, 0, 5.8922, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1.2759)
```

---

You might also be interested in checking out the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module which is built on top of `numpy`, and which takes parsing CSV to an even higher level of luxury: It has a [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) function whose `parse_dates = True` parameter will automatically parse date strings (using [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2)).

Using pandas, your csv could be parsed with

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates = [0,1], header = None,
                    names=('Date', 'Stock', 'Action', 'Amount') +
                    tuple('col{i}'.format(i=i) for i in range(22)))
```

Note there is no need to specify the `make_date` function`. Just to be clear --`pands.read_csv`returns a`DataFrame, not a numpy array. The `DataFrame` may actually be more useful for your purpose, but you should be aware it is a different object with a whole new world of methods to exploit and explore.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this man!!!!

I just had one follow up question. Now say I want to move some of these values into independent arrays... How exactly do I get to doing that?

Comment: Ok... I've got the data in.. How do I call it? do I simply do arr['Stock']??

Comment: If you just want to parse certain columns, use the `usecols = [...]` parameter in `genfromtxt`. It allows you to specify a list of column names or column index numbers to be used in the array.

Comment: Yes! `arr['Stock']` returns the `Stock` column numpy array.

Comment: Could I possibly use numbers to call the columns? If I want to say run a loop across the columns? Could I possibly call something like arr[1] instead of arr['Stock'] ???

Comment: No, `arr[1]` would refer to the second row. To loop over columns, you could  do something like `for col in ('Stock','Action','Amount'): arr[col] = ...`.